# Should one of these be closed as a duplicate of the other? If so, which one?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, vote-to-close

Two well written, well received questions each with several well written, well received answers. Each now has one close vote as a duplicate of the other.

- January 2019 [Why are probes that tend to explore outer system always launched to go outwards instead of straight upwards or downwards?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33289/12102) **Q:** +28,  top **A:** +50, +36, +28, +5...
- September 2013 [Is there any reason to send space probes along the plane of our solar system instead of perpendicular to the plane of our solar system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1858/12102) **Q:** +10,  top **A:** +13, +9, +5, +4...

The 2019 posts probably have more absolute votes because of higher readership in 2019 than in 2013.

Can anyone see enough difference between the two so that they should both remain open? Is this a good candidate for merging to keep all good answers on an equal footing, or should one be closed?

If the latter, then is there a way to decide which should be closed as duplicate of the other? I think that the order in which they appear to close-voters will determine this and that's not necessarily the best method.

Comment: There's actually a third: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/834/58. And we ruled to leave them both open last time this came up (I voted for close one as a duplicate). It does seem we need to do something about this now that we have three duplicates.

Comment: They're all helpful, but we need to remember that duplicates and their answers stick around. So I think we need to bite the bullet and pick one to be the primary and close the other two as duplicates of the primary.

Comment: The best way is to pick the clearest worded question as the primary.

Comment: All right, they're both hovering at four close votes now. I should probably take action if we don't want one accidentally being the primary.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with the newer one since it also includes this question: "What would we find if we go straight upwards and downwards?"

Comment: I think so too! Yes that is my favorite

Comment: Someone beat me to it

Comment: I still don't quite understand why this is the best, the open question no longer points to the closed question(s) and all of those answers. Is there any kind of "there are more answers to this question at these other closed questions" message?

Comment: They show up in the linked questions. I decided against closing the third one because it has a slightly different scope, but I'll add it to the linked questions.

Comment: ya okay I see, the linked questions, got it.

Comment: @called2voyage another similar situation? [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37804/12102) vs [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13162/12102)

Comment: I agree with the duplicate voters there.